# Angular translate StaticFilesLoader doesn't work

Tags: angular-translate

[This](http://plnkr.co/edit/Hw4iMz?p=preview) Angular translation demo doesn't work!

Can somebody provide me with a working example? I can't get multilingual support to work.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp" >
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="https://rawgithub.com/PascalPrecht/bower-angular-translate/master/angular-translate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://rawgithub.com/PascalPrecht/bower-angular-translate-loader-static-files/master/angular-translate-loader-static-files.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="Ctrl">
<h1 translate>HEADLINE</h1>
<button ng-click="switchLanguage('de_DE')" translate>LANG_DE_DE</button>
<button ng-click="switchLanguage('en_US')" translate>LANG_EN_US</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/KpCfZofLKYaZa4SXdKHS?p=preview).

The bug was a simple typo.

You had:

```
$translateProvider.uses('en_US')
```

Should be:

```
$translateProvider.use('en_US')
```